# could I generate mybaits Mapper dynamically?

Tags: code-generation, mybatis, mybatis-generator

```
<javaClientGenerator type="XMLMAPPER" targetPackage="com.aaa.${module}.domain.mapper"  targetProject="src/main/resources">
  <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
</javaClientGenerator>
```

the var ${module} could be the value of domainObjectName in the table config.

```
    <table schema="test" tableName="account" domainObjectName="Account" >
      <property name="useActualColumnNames" value="true"/>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you most likely need to create a custom javaClientGenerator.  I don't think the enableSubPackages property works quite that way.  In your config file you would have:

```
<javaClientGenerator type="com.mydomain.MyJavaMapperGenerator" targetPackage="com.aaa.${module}.domain.mapper"  targetProject="src/main/java">
</javaClientGenerator>
```

And then you would need to subclass the existing JavaMapperGenerator with your own version.  Something like option 1 or 2 below. **Option 2 is the one I would probably go with given the unexpected complexity of option 1**.

**Option 1 -** What makes this difficult is the mapper type is stored in a private variable so you have to create a whole new Interface object copying the values over from the original:

```
public class MyJavaMapperGenerator extends JavaMapperGenerator {

    @Override
    public List<CompilationUnit> getCompilationUnits() {
        List<CompilationUnit> compliationUnits = super.getCompilationUnits();
        List<CompilationUnit> newCompliationUnits = new ArrayList<>();
        Interface mapper = (Interface)compliationUnits.get(0);
        String mapperType = mapper.getType().getFullyQualifiedName();
        Interface newMapper = new Interface(mapperType.replace("${module}",
            introspectedTable.getFullyQualifiedTable().getDomainObjectName().toLowerCase()));

        newMapper.getJavaDocLines().addAll(mapper.getJavaDocLines());
        newMapper.setVisibility(mapper.getVisibility());
        newMapper.setStatic(mapper.isStatic());
        newMapper.setFinal(mapper.isFinal());
        newMapper.getAnnotations().addAll(mapper.getAnnotations());

        newMapper.addImportedTypes(mapper.getImportedTypes());
        newMapper.getStaticImports().addAll(mapper.getStaticImports());
        newMapper.getSuperInterfaceTypes().addAll(mapper.getSuperInterfaceTypes());
        newMapper.getMethods().addAll(mapper.getMethods());
        newMapper.getFileCommentLines().addAll(mapper.getFileCommentLines());

        newCompliationUnits.add(newMapper);

        return newCompliationUnits;
    }

}
```

**Option 2 -** Though it's a little messy, I would probably copy-paste the entire getCompilationsUnits() method from JavaMapperGenerator and modify the single line that sets the type:

```
public class MyJavaMapperGenerator extends JavaMapperGenerator {

    @Override
    public List<CompilationUnit> getCompilationUnits() {
        ...
        //FullyQualifiedJavaType type = new FullyQualifiedJavaType(
        //        introspectedTable.getMyBatis3JavaMapperType());
        FullyQualifiedJavaType type = new FullyQualifiedJavaType(
                introspectedTable.getMyBatis3JavaMapperType().replace("${module}",
                introspectedTable.getFullyQualifiedTable().getDomainObjectName()
                                 .toLowerCase()));
        ...
    }

}
```